# RStudio/ R - Make new df of rows where values in a column exact match a string (faster speed needed)

Tags: r, string, dataframe, match

Sorry I have looked for solutions but couldn't find what was needed. I am quite new to R and have used only matlab before (hence am still trying to work out how not to use loops).

I have a df with academic papers in it (one row per paper).

Main df

```
Fields                              Date       Title
Biology; Neuroscience               2016       How do we know when XXX
Music; Engineering; Art             2011       Can we get the XXX
Biotechnology; Biology & Chemistry  2007       When will we find XXX
History; Biology                    2006       Where does the XXXX
```

In one column ('Fields') there is a list of subject names, with multiple fields separated by a colon. I want to find all rows (papers) that have an exact match to a specific field name (e.g., 'Biology'). Then, make a new df with all those rows (papers). Importantly, however, I want not to get fields that partially match (e.g., 'Biology & Chemistry').

New df - just for those rows

```
Fields                              Date       Title
Biology; Neuroscience               2016       How do we know when XXX
History; Biology                    2006       Where does the XXXX
```

i.e., does not also select Biotechnology; Biology & Chemistry 2007 When will we find XXX which has the word 'Biology' in it

My first thought was to get each field name in its own column using splitstring, then loop through each column using which to find the exact matches for the name. Because there are up to 200 columns (field names) this takes ages! It's taking up to an hour to find and pull all the rows. I would obviously like something faster.

I know in R you can avoid loops by applying etc., but I cant think how to use that here.

This is what it looks like when I split the author names into separate columns

```
Field1        Field2                     Date       Title
Biology       Neuroscience               2016       How do we know when XXX
```

This is my code so far (note: there is a white space in front of the names once I split them up)

```
# Get list of columns to cycle through (they all start with 'sA')
names <- data[,grep("^sA", colnames(data))]
collist <- colnames(names)
names[collist] <- sapply(names[collist],as.character)
collist <- collist[-1]


Loop to get new df from matching rows
for (l in 1:length(namesUniq$Names)) {
  namecurr <- namesUniq$Names[l]
  namecurrSP <- paste0(" ", namecurr)

  # Get data for that field
    dfall <- data[which(data$sA1 == namecurr), ]

  for (d in 1:length(collist)) {
    dcol <- collist[d]
    dfall <- rbind(dfall, data[which(data[, dcol] == namecurrSP), ])
    rm(dcol)
  }
  rm(d)
```

Something that runs quickly would be really useful. Thank you for any help!

grepl does not work - it pulls other partial match strings (like 'Biology & Chemistry' when I want 'Biology' only)

```
dfall <- subset(data, grepl(namecurr, Field, fixed = TRUE))
```

For some reason, which does not work when I do it this way (rows works, rows2 does not - it selects rows outside the bounds of my df)

```
dfall <- rbind(data[rows, ], data[rows2, ])
```

Comment: I am surprised when you say `grepl()` does not work. What regex did you try with it? Did you try `grepl(pattern = "Biology;", ...)`? (where you fill in the `x` arguments, etc. as appropriate where I've placed `...`)

Comment: this also does not work: dfall <- subset(data, grepl(namecurr, unlist(strsplit(Field, ",")), fixed = TRUE))

Comment: Sorry, I dont know what regex means :s the pattern I put in is always the variable namecurr, which changes on each, being taken from an array, e.g., namecurr <- names[l], which would be something like 'Biology'

Comment: In that case, can  you try `paste0(namecurr, ";")` in place of `namecurr`? This will avoid things like matching `Biology & Chemistry;` when you only want things like `Biology;`

Comment: dfall <- subset(data, grepl(namecurr, Field, fixed = TRUE))

pulls 'BIOLOGY' and 'MICROBIOLOGY' for instance, I just want the former

Comment: tried the paste0 trick with the semicolon - unfortunately this doesnt get ones that are at the end of the list (no following semicolon). If I dont use the paste0 semicolon, I get BIOLOGY and MICROBIOLOGY

Comment: If you have fields that can end in "BIOLOGY" that you don't want to pick up, you can just use a negative look behind assertion as well. Working example: `namecurr <- "BIOLOGY"; search_pattern <- paste0("(?<!\\w)", namecurr, ";"); grepl(pattern = search_pattern, x = x, perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)`. I would suggest reading about regular expressions via `help("regex")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without a `dput` of your example data here is a example that can be used

data

```
test <- c("Biology; Neuroscience","Music; Engineering; Art","Biotechnology; Biology & Chemistry","History; Biology")
```

code:

```
test[sapply(strsplit(test,"; "), function(x) any(x=="Biology"))]
```

output:

```
[1] "Biology; Neuroscience" "History; Biology"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how many different subsets you'll be pulling from your main dataframe but thought I would take @Daniel-O solution a little farther for you and demonstrate a `tidyverse` solution.

You can think of it as make a `Biology_df` by starting with the `Main_df` and `filter`ing for all the rows where after we `str_split` the `Fields` column by semi-colon and space (`"; "`) there are `any` pieces of the split that exactly match `Biology`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

Main_df
#>                               Fields Date                   Title
#> 1              Biology; Neuroscience 2016 How do we know when XXX
#> 2            Music; Engineering; Art 2011      Can we get the XXX
#> 3 Biotechnology; Biology & Chemistry 2007     Where does the XXXX
#> 4                   History; Biology 2006     Where does the XXXX

Biology_df <- 
  Main_df %>% 
    filter(str_split(Fields, "; ") %>% 
           map_lgl( ~ any(.x == "Biology")
                  )
           )

Biology_df
#>                  Fields Date                   Title
#> 1 Biology; Neuroscience 2016 How do we know when XXX
#> 2      History; Biology 2006     Where does the XXXX
```

Based upon the little snippet of data you show

```r
Fields <- c("Biology; Neuroscience","Music; Engineering; Art","Biotechnology; Biology & Chemistry","History; Biology")
Date <- c("2016", "2011", "2007", "2006")
Title <- c("How do we know when XXX", "Can we get the XXX", "Where does the XXXX", "Where does the XXXX")
Main_df <- data.frame(Fields, Date, Title)
```